# How to group a number of methods in a class with doxygen?

Tags: c++, doxygen

Doxygen is a very good c++ code documentation tool. I am wondering if it has the feature to group a number of related methods in a class and give them a meaning comments. For example:

```
class A : public B
{
public:
    //// Begin group: Methods to implement class B's interface.

    //! ...
    void b1();

    //! ...
    void b1();

    //// End group

};
```

And the group information is shown in the doxygen generated class document. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use @name tag to reach the similar functionality. Take a look at the example, that's easy.

```
/**
 * @name Appends data to the container.
 *
 * @param tag Name of the data entry
 * @param value Data value
 */
//@{
/**
 * @brief Documentation for this overload
 */
void append(const std::string & tag, bool value);

/**
 * @brief Documentation for this overload
 */
void append(const std::string & tag, int8_t value);

void append(const std::string & tag, int16_t value);
void append(const std::string & tag, int32_t value);
//@}
```

It produces the following output:
[image]